# set a Javascript variable with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to write a game where you roll the dice and get half a quote and you have to guess if it matches the half that you were originally given. I am using AJAX and everything works fine right up until the end when I send a variable from php to javascript using

```
echo  '<script>currentQuote = $currentQuote;</script>';
```

It shows up on the page but when I check the value of currentQuote in JS it is undefined. Here is a link to a simplified version of the game just showing my problem.http://workwithu.com/Games/Game15snip.php The PHP code which you cannot see is:

```
<?php
$response = mt_rand(1,6);
echo $response;
$currentQuote=$response;
echo '<script>currentQuote = $currentQuote;</script>';//this not working
echo "<br>";
echo "currentQuote is:";
echo $currentQuote; //this shows on the screen fine
?>
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I have run out of ideas to try.
Thanks

Comment: Read that wondefull article please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 4):

Basic PHP syntax. `'`-quoted strings do **NOT** interpolate variable values. If you do a `view source` on your page, you'll see a literal

```
<script>current Quote = $currentQuote</script>
```

in the page's source. Switch to a `"`-quoted string:

```
echo "<script>currentQuote = $currentQuote;</script>";//this not working
     ^---note                                       ^---note
```

Comment: Also factor that $currentQuote may be a string, which could resolve to currentQuote = Some string that will break js; - btw I see it is a result of mt rand, but in general the comment is for anyone else, not you Marc B.

Comment: OK, I tried using double quotes and still got currentQuote=undefined. Maybe I should have mentioned that the PHP is coming from two files on the server via Ajax and I am trying to store what I get from the first response to pass via Javascript to the next file using Ajax.Maybe I can only use one PHP file and have to store all the values in there, but everything I read says that a variable can be stored with Javascript using <?php echo and although it show on the page it is not being stored so I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ' -Quoted sting you should use.

```
echo '<script>currentQuote = '.$currentQuote.';</script>';
```

or use " -quoted

```
echo "<script>currentQuote = $currentQuote;</script>";
```